# Select and print out Data from MySQL with php, not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table ("module databas") in a database in MySQL and I need to print out that table (very simple, two rows "Fnamn" and "Enamn" with names in it) on the server by writing a php script and using MySQL. Problem is : it doesn't work. The html part of the document (.php) works perfectly fine (the h1 appears on the screen) but I get nothing else. What could be the problem ?

Tried a few different ways to do it, even by copy/pasting from w3 schools (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) and changing a few variables, but nothing (had a "0 results" with this W3 one, and now nothing with the new one).

```
<h1>Script modul</h1>

<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "antony";
$password = "thepassword";
$dbname = "antony";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM moduledatabas";

$result = mysqli_query($query);

if (!$result) {
    $message = 'Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['Fnamn'];
    echo $row['Enamn'];
}

mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Comment: Read up on using mysqli. For some reason you are making a mysqli connection then using mysql (mixing stuff up). Never use mysql as its deprecated.

Comment: phpmyadmin is a tool to access the database and manage it. It is not a DB itself and certainly this question has nothing to do with it.

Comment: there is a space in your table name, please use the `  to encapsulate the whole name : \`module databas\`  it should be then working.

Comment: On mixing up `mysql` with `mysqli`, see [`mysqli::query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), example 1, object oriented style, since you start out by creating a mysqli object.

Comment: Have corrected mysql to mysqli and changed "module databas" to "moduledatabas" (in phpmyadmin and the code) and am getting now : "whole query : SELECT * FROM moduledatabas". What could that mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not pass `$conn` in your `mysqli_query()`,just change your code like below  :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM moduledatabas";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

For more info refer *[mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)*

Comment: You my friend are a lifesaver. Thank you, working now (ant thanks everyone) ! It prints out all the names now, but not in order (meaning, all the surnames and then all the family names). What if I need to print out everyting like surname-family name like in a table ?